# document.querySelector returns null for existing element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, queryselector

I am trying to extract company name from specific website but even element exist in the html queryselector returning null
I have tried using DOMContentLoaded, adding script at the bottom of the HTML and adding defer to the script but still it is not working

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const companyNameQuery = document.querySelector("#fixedCpName > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.col-md-5 > h1");
  const countryNameQuery = document.querySelector("#fixedCpName > div > div.row.marg-t-15 > div.col-lg-6.col-md-5 > div.pull-left > span.company-country");
  console.log(countryNameQuery);
 });
```

Comment: How do you know the element does exist?

Comment: I copied the selector from the html of the page itself @Bergi

Comment: The elements you're looking for are probably added _after_ the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires as is the case with many dynamic web pages

Comment: then what should I do solve this bug @Phil

Comment: You have several unattractive options... add a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), set a suitably large timeout delay or poll the document for the element at regular intervals until it exists. I'd probably go for the 3rd one

Comment: @ks_ html does not contain selectors